# Posting the same program in three different languages in three different sections

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, multi-language

If I made three programs in three different languages, that do the same thing, could I post all three of them and have them connect to one another in order for the review to be successful?

Let's say I write three programs that accomplish the same goal in three languages: Perl, Python, and Ruby. I then post them all in their respective section, then create a link to the other two programs in each post. Would this be considered wrong. or would this be acceptable? Wouldn't they need to see all the languages the program is written in to make a valid review of the program itself?

I ask this because I did such a thing. I first posted all the programs in the same post, with three different tags. I figured this would be acceptable but I can understand why it wouldn't be. I then corrected my error and posted the programs (mind you the same program is written in three different languages) in three different posts with their respective tag. I then went ahead and added a link to the other two languages on the post, which was removed. I don't understand how it would be wrong to show all of the languages.

Comment: While related, I disagree that the duplicate target is the same question as this.  It is in fact, the reverse question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Posting three separate questions and having them link to each other is a perfectly alright thing to do.

The removing of your links was either an error, a case of two edits being done at the same time, or a deliberate edit that I would disagree with.

Please go ahead and post three questions, one for each language, and feel free to have them link to each other.

You may also want to consider to post your questions a bit apart, as answers to one of the languages might improve the code for another language.